# facing issue with @Relation in roomdb android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room

```
 public class StockRelation extends Item {
        @Relation(parentColumn = "mpc", entityColumn = "itempc", entity = Location.class)
        public List<Location> locationList;
    }

    public class RStockRelation extends StockRelation{
       @Relation(parentColumn = "mpc", entityColumn = "location_itemid", entity = Location.class)
       public List<Location> locationList;
    }
```

here only the @Relation is getting change whereas the other things are the same.
and I want to do a sort order for locationlist based on a column in the Location table in the query itself.
So how to have final data in one object instead of two different StockRelation and RStockRelation.
Is there any other way I can fix this

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you have two tables (entities) and in general you want apply two left joins from first table to the second one on different fields - to get in result your first object with connected two different location lists (but use Room-Relation annotation instead of left joins).

If it's what you want, try this:

```
public class StockRelation extends Item {
@Relation(parentColumn = "mpc", entityColumn = "itempc", entity = Location.class)
public List<Location> locationList1;
@Relation(parentColumn = "mpc", entityColumn = "location_itemid", entity = Location.class)
public List<Location> locationList2;
}
```

Comment: Yes with left join we can do this but all the location objects will be separate not getting grouped by mpc column each will have only one location. whereas your solution will give me two lists like duplicate and it will take more memory if there are items more than 1000

Comment: Well, then I would recommend you to add in your post some simple examples with data in your tables and what outputs you want to get by tables relations. Otherwise it's not clear from the text what specific task you're trying to solve